# Iterate over a column, open worksheet, and Copy/Paste

Tags: excel, vba, iteration

Though my initial question was in regards to a piece within my code, I chose to ask the question related to all of the code I have as I'm unsure if I have any other mistakes (if it isn't clear, I am very new to VBA, 3 days new). I have been obsessed with this task for the past 5 days and need to sleep.

Code objective summary:
1- Iterate over a column
2- If condition is met within that column, present dialogue box to select workbooks.
3- Copy/Paste from the opened workbooks to the "home" spreadsheet.

Narrative:
I am trying to make an interactive collaborative program where users can populate information ("Weekly Staff Production" sheet, column D which is a drop down). I want to write a macro that runs when:

1. A condition is met in column D (value of cell = "Coord Issue")
2. When condition is met, the user is prompted to select workbooks (prmpt() routine)
3. A dialogue box is opened where they make the selection of these workbooks
4. The data of the values to be copied is on a sheet that has a common name across all opened workbooks (i.e. "Calculated Split Times"). I want to copy a certain range (A14:U54) from all of these sheets and paste them in ThisWorkbook. The Paste always occurs below the last cell used (maybe if we leave a row in between can help with readability)

I apologize for this verbose explanation, and appreciate all the help. For reference, I have put the files [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/34ab505d88bd5e2725f97e3fda9ba1a120210705172238/03c627) and they contain:
1- Destination workbook (where the data will be copied to)
2- Source workbooks (where the data is copied from)

Below is also the code, however, it does not reflect all that I want to do (which is listed above).

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Cell As Range

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("D")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each Cell In Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("D"))
        If Cell.Value = "Coord Issue" Then Call prmpt
    Next Cell


   End If
End Sub
Sub prmpt()
Dim issue_asset As Integer
issue_asset = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value
msgbox ("Select intersections affected by " & issue_asset), vbInformation, "Hossam"
Dim i As Integer
Dim filename As Variant
Dim filenamestr As Variant
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Integer

lastRow = 1

'Opening File dialog box

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'Enabling multiple files select
.AllowMultiSelect = True
.Filters.Clear

'Only Excel files can be selected
.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"

If .Show = True Then
    For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        'to record a list of the opened files
        'Opening selected file
        'For Each filename In .SelectedItems
       ' MsgBox filename
        'Next
        'For Each filename In .SelectedItems
            'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.
            
            filenamestr = .SelectedItems(i)
              'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
              Set wsCopy = Workbooks(filenamestr).Worksheets("Sheet4") 'testing with the raw data sheet, eventually this will be the calculated split times sheet
              
              Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet6")
            
              '3. Copy & Paste Data
              wsCopy.Range("A11:U54").Copy _
              wsDest.Range("A" & lastRow)
           'Next filename

        Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(i)
        filenamestr = .SelectedItems(1)
        lastRow = lastRow + 55
    Next i
End If

End With

Debug.Print (filenamestr) 'testing the whether filenamestr records the paths

End Sub
```

Comment: @toddleson that link is `VB.Net` not `vba`.  AFAIK `iterator` is not defined in vba

Comment: @HOSSAM subscript out of range means that the name you put for `Workbooks()` or `Worksheets()` was not found. Like if you search for "sheet99" but there is no sheet named "sheet99" you will get "subscript out of range". Try doing those two methods separately to see which one is the problem and then double check your input to see if it is what you expected.

Comment: Got it, I was able to find the issue. Thanks a lot for the help. I will change the status of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of question (Copy from workbook to workbook) has been asked and answered dozens of times on here and there are many many great answers to reference and learn from. But that only takes care of objective #4.

Objective #1 can be completed by using the [Worksheet_Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event or the [Workbook_SheetChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) event. These are triggered every time any cell formula/value is edited. So it would trigger when your users are entering new data.

If you have a specific set of sheets you want to monitor, put a Worksheet_Change script into those sheet's code module. Something like the following:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("D")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each Cell In Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("D"))
            If Cell.Value = "Coord Issue" Then Call prmpt
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to watch for changes on every sheet in the workbook, put a script into the Workbook's code module like the following:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Columns("D")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each Cell In Intersect(Target, Sh.Columns("D"))
            If Cell.Value = "Coord Issue" Then Call prmpt
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

In my example scripts I wrote `Call prmpt` to reference the code you have already written. But that won't work if your sub `prmpt` is not available from the calling code module. The sub `prmpt` will need to be in the same workbook or will need to be properly referenced like `Call YourOtherWorkbook.prmpt`

To explain the other parts of my example script:
[Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) can be used to check if the changed cells were in Column D by seeing if the returned value from Intersect is Not `Nothing`. If the changed range was in column D then the returned range will be those cells and therefore Not `Nothing`.

Then we can loop through that range cell by cell checking if any of the newly changed values meet the criteria. If they meet the criteria, we can call on the sub you have written.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer this question, I sincerely appreciate it. I understand that the copy/paste from other workbooks has been asked a lot of times, however my question is more specific.
I want to copy/paste from ONLY the selected/opened workbooks (please see what I am trying to do with the ".SelectedItems"). I am tryin to iterate over all objects in the collection using a for loop to do the following:
For each item in the collection, copy/paste into ThisWorkbook

Comment: Adding to the above, I want to copy the data from the sheets ONLY opened by the user through the dialog box. That is, when a user is prompted to select the files from the dialog box, these files in turn are copied from.

Comment: @HOSSAM After you have retrieved the list of workbooks by whichever method you choose. You're in the same position as every other copy/paste question asker. You have one or more target workbooks and a destination workbook and you want to copy data from some sheets onto the destination sheets. There is not an answer I can provide that you wont find a dozen times just by searching "[vba] copy paste workbook" in the Stack Overflow search bar.

Comment: I've been doing just that and will keep looking into it. I have updated my code, however now I run into another issue "subscript out of range" on the "Set wscopy..." line. Please see the updated code, and if you have any idea on why it's happening and how to solve it I would be yet again very appreciative!